# Merge two list into a single list

Tags: java, list, collections, merge

I have a ArrayList as below.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> a = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

Where ArrayList `'a'` contains two ArrayList of string as below.

```
[a,b,c,d] & [1,2,3,4]
```

How to merge these two list into a single list as below.

```
[a,b,c,d,1,2,3,4]
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java ArrayList: Merging ArrayLists within ArrayLists to create one ArrayList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975783/java-arraylist-merging-arraylists-within-arraylists-to-create-one-arraylist)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just iterate through all the inner lists of `a` using `foreach` loop and `addAll` to `result` arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> merged = new ArrayList<String>();

for(ArrayList<String> list : a){
   merged.addAll(list);
}
```

EDIT:
As @Lubo pointed out.

Note that this way you can end up with many arrays being created and thrown away internally in `ArrayList`. If you have large lists (number of contained elements), consider looking here: [Union List](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13868352/11152683)

Comment: Note that this way you can end up with many references "duplicated". If you have large lists (number of contained elements), consider looking here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13868352/11152683

Answer (score 7):

You combine a `foreach` loop and the `addAll` method.

**Example**

```
ArrayList<String> combined = new ArrayList<String>();

for(ArrayList<String> list : a) {
    combined.addAll(list);
}
```

**How this works?**

A `for each` loop will traverse through every member of a `Collection`. It has a temporary variable, in this case `list` that it assigns the current element too. All you're doing is adding every element inside each value for `list`, to one `ArrayList` named `combined`.

Answer (score 4):

This should work

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> a = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (ArrayList<String> arrayList : a) {
            result.addAll(arrayList);
        }
```

Look into main loop and get each list in it and add to your result list.

Comment: And +1 to you for being awesome.

Answer (score 4):

We have some other ways too, If you can use Apache commons-collection

```
ListUtils.union(java.util.List list1, java.util.List list2)
```

Returns a new list containing the second list appended to the first list.

Answer (score 2):

Use ArrayList.addAll(). Something like this should work (assuming lists contain String objects; you should change accordingly).

```
List<String> combined = new ArrayList<String>();
combined.addAll(firstArrayList);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need an Iterable, you can use [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
Iterables.concat(Iterable<? extends Iterable<? extends T>> inputs)
```

And if you really need a List, you can cast a resulting Iterable to a List using this:

```
Lists.newArrayList(Iterable<? extends E> elements)
```

or

```
Lists.newLinkedList(Iterable<? extends E> elements)
```

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 streams provide another solution:

```
List<List<String>> list = Arrays.asList(
        Arrays.asList("1", "2"),
        Arrays.asList("3", "4"),
        Arrays.asList("5", "6")
);

List<String> merged = list
        .stream()
        .reduce(new ArrayList<>(),(accumulator, sublist) -> {accumulator.addAll(sublist);return accumulator;});

System.out.println(merged);
```

It is similar to the accepted answer: you loop through your list (using `Stream.reduce`) to add all of your sublists elements to your `merged` list.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<Integer> one = Arrays.asList(1, 2,3);
    List<Integer> two = Arrays.asList(4, 5,6);
    List<Integer> out = Stream.of(one, two)
            .collect(ArrayList::new, (listStream, item) -> listStream.addAll(item), (item1, item2) -> {});
    System.out.println(out);
```

Answer (score -1):

## Merging lists without loop with [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)

Using [FluentIterable.transformAndConcat](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html#transformAndConcat(com.google.common.base.Function)).

> Applies function to each element of this fluent iterable and returns a fluent iterable with the concatenated combination of results. function returns an Iterable of results.

### Usage

```
List<String> combined = FluentIterable.from(a)
      .transformAndConcat(Functions.identity())
      .toList();
```